# About Get Response command in javacard

Tags: javacard, apdu, getresponse

I'm confused about Get Response command. I thought I know it but actually I don't.

I wanna know the mechanism in which the card returns 1000-bytes data in case 4. I guess the command is as follows. Please let me know the correct one if it is wrong.

```
(Card) <== [CLA] [INS] [P1] [P2] [Lc] [Data] [Le] // response data size is 1000 bytes
(Card) ==> 6100

(Card) <== 00 C0 00 00 00
(Card) ==> [Data(256)] 6100

(Card) <== 00 C0 00 00 00
(Card) ==> [Data(256)] 6100

(Card) <== 00 C0 00 00 00
(Card) ==> [Data(256)] 61E8

(Card) <== 00 C0 00 00 E8
(Card) ==> [Data(232)] 9000 (61E8 was my mistake)
```

**Questions**

1. Is the above APDU correct ?
2. What is the [Le] in first command ?
3. How to implement the GET RESPONSE in java applet ?
4. How is the method to implement different according to T=0/T=1 card ? (When I googled, I saw the information about the T=0/T=1 card but I don't understand.)

I hope any response or URL of the related information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions:

1. It seems largely correct to me, except for (2) and the final remark;
2. You don't send both a Lc and Le field for T=0, in a case 4 command (command data and response data) only Lc and the command data is send - you could also say that Le is empty as it is an encoding in bytes;
3. T=0 is handled by the Java Card OS, you should not have to implement this yourself;
4. T=1 does not use or need GET RESPONSE as both T=1 and T=CL are higher level protocols - the layer beneath APDU's already take care of this. Furthermore extended length support may have been implemented.

Finally, the card should of course return `9000` or a status word indicating a warning or error instead of `61E8` for the last command (this was subsequently fixed in the question as mistake in the question).

Note that you should *not* blindly assume that the response will contain the amount of bytes requested. An Le byte with value `00` for instance indicates a **maximum** response size of 256 bytes.

This is all defined in ISO/IEC 7816-4, chapter 5.3.4: Response chaining

The current version is 2013(E) at the time of writing. It's payware (but Google isn't).

Comment: Anything missing from my answer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thesedays I'm busy and so I don't have time to think about this problem. But sometimes I'm trying to visit here and study about it. Thanks again.

Comment: Does the comment 2 mean that the case 4 command is not sent into T=0 card?

Comment: I modified the above APDU. what do you think about it? Command1 : [CLA] [INS] [P1] [P2] [Lc] [Data] SW1 : 6100 // Command2 : 00 C0 00 00 00 SW2 : 6100 // Command3 : 00 C0 00 00 00 SW3 : 6100 // Command4 : 00 C0 00 00 00 SW4 : 61E8 // Command5 : 00 C0 00 00 E8 SW5 : 9000

Comment: Yes, case 4 does not exist for T=0. Above looks better (except for case 4 in T=0, obviously). Please try and not change the question in a big way, otherwise answers will be outdated.