# Select by AID command is not working

Tags: smartcard, apdu, emv

I want to re-develop new desktop application to read information from EMV smart card and **I have logs from previous (working) application**.

Assume, there is an app with AID = 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 (DDDDDDDD) in the EMV smart card.

I am sending APDU command: 00 A4 04 00 08 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 00 and getting timeout exception (timeout = 60s).

I tried to send APDU command: 00 A4 04 00 08 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 and got response code = 61 37.

I tried to select file 1PAY.SYS.DDF01, immediately got response = 6a82 (it is right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed library from RXTXserial to JSSC and it solved my problem. Now I get responses without GET RESPONSE request. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 5):

Error code 61XX means you will receive your data after calling Get Response command with Le=XX:

Example:

```
--> 00 A4 04 00 08 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44
<-- 61 37
--> 00 C0 00 00 37
<-- some data of length 0x37 and status code 90 00.
```

Related question:
[About Get Response command in javacard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24711277/about-get-response-command-in-javacard)

Docs by Oracle:

> There may be several APDU connections open at the same time using
>   different logical channels with the same card. However, since APDU
>   protocol is synchronous, there can be no interleaving of command and
>   their response APDUs across logical channels. Between the receipt of
>   the command APDU and the sending of the response APDU to that command,
>   only one logical channel is active. For T=0 protocol, for case 4 and
>   case 2 command APDUs the card may respond with '61 XX' or '6C XX'.
>   These special cases MUST be handled by the implementation in the
>   following manner:
>
> '61 XX': The implementation MUST send GET RESPONSE to the card to get the response data before any other command is sent.
>   '6C XX': The implementation MUST resend the command after setting Le equal to XX received from the card before any other command is
>   sent.
>
> In both the cases discussed above, the implementation MUST make sure
>   that between sending the command APDU, receiving status word '61 XX'
>   or '6C XX', and sending GET RESPONSE or resending the command APDU
>   with Le set to XX respectively, there MUST not be any other APDU
>   exchange on any logical channel with the card. In case the status word
>   '61 XX' is received multiple times successively from the card, the
>   implementation must accumulate all the response data received from the
>   card before returning it to the J2ME application. J2ME applications
>   MUST remain oblivious of the exchanges mentioned above and should only
>   get the response received as a result of the above operations.

Comment: Or very terse: This is T=0 protocol, you must explicitly fetch the card response, with the length indicated.

Comment: @guidot Could you give more details?

Comment: @vojta I tried your example, but I am getting timeout exception after 00 C0 00 00 37.

Comment: @SparX Hmm, so it is a more complicated issue... Could you try it with another reader?

Comment: Half-duplex is no difference to T=1; the most important distinction is character-oriented (T=0) vs. block-oriented (T=1). The Get Response looks okay (see ISO 7816-3 for T=0 protocol, and part 4 for the Get Response command). Timeout instead of a error status surely indicates, that something  is wrong on very low level.

Comment: @guidot Let me give you some more information. I am using ICT 3k5 card reader. On Ubuntu platform using Java8 via RXTXserial.jar+RXTXserial.so. I have logs from Windows with this card reader. That old application sends 00 A4 04 00 08 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 **00** command once and gets response with data.

Comment: Don't know the reader; if you are using Java: one possible pitfall is, that you code the LC byte (*08* before 44..44) yourself. Java computes and adds this itself from the byte array for the command data field.